# How to create a side scroller with two rows of elements instead of one row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, materialize

I am trying to create a side scroller with 2 boxes per visible at a time using flex (One on top and one underneath)

As you can see on the first bunch of boxes below, I have it successfully horizontally scrolling, but I want there to be two rows of boxes in view instead of one row.

```css
.box-flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.box-flex-row > .m4 {
  min-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="section">
    <div class="row box-flex-row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr class="hr-bottom-line">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Stuff</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent auctor, nibh sit amet ultrices gravida, tortor magna pretium nunc, at ultricies ipsum libero ac mi. Sed a dictum turpis. Integer vitae ante sed neque ultrices congue. Sed euismod
        nunc id magna aliquet dictum id id erat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum porta mauris ut sapien molestie lacinia. Sed ullamcorper purus a lorem porta, et imperdiet mauris imperdiet.
        Nullam sit amet neque nibh. Pellentesque non magna sed diam tincidunt accumsan quis quis magna. Vivamus urna turpis, ornare id malesuada vel, fringilla eget elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
        egestas. Suspendisse posuere mi eget augue scelerisque euismod. Phasellus quis aliquam dolor, et dapibus urna. Proin suscipit et ligula at semper. Ut tristique magna vitae finibus pellentesque. Phasellus tincidunt tortor et sem posuere, et feugiat
        tellus lacinia. Praesent commodo ullamcorper eros quis suscipit. Nam sed justo tortor. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque ut lacus sit amet lacus mattis aliquet. Morbi eu purus elit. Aenean rhoncus, lectus vitae aliquet fringilla, eros metus fermentum
        metus, vel malesuada arcu turpis non dolor. Curabitur non ex sed est vehicula efficitur. Fusce vel enim in lectus viverra luctus. Fusce ac sapien porttitor, consectetur massa ut, suscipit nulla. Fusce nec massa lobortis, tincidunt ex eget, ultrices
        felis. Vivamus turpis justo, varius vel tincidunt sed, consequat a purus. Aliquam ultrices eros fermentum nunc dignissim, quis maximus eros malesuada. Vivamus non porttitor quam, id efficitur libero. Donec vulputate posuere viverra. Fusce iaculis
        tellus sit amet orci consequat, at sagittis magna rhoncus. Maecenas ac dapibus est, vel auctor lectus. Integer porta lacus dui, eu scelerisque enim iaculis id. Aliquam eget pulvinar nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur et rutrum sem.
        Cras viverra pharetra est. Etiam at molestie ipsum. Donec varius pulvinar tortor, in semper lacus. Nunc vel luctus dui. In eu neque et erat eleifend sodales. Pellentesque id ligula sed risus tempor maximus. Quisque turpis felis, condimentum et
        bibendum ac, congue eu arcu. Aenean rutrum ante et dui pharetra, sed mattis risus accumsan. Mauris vulputate venenatis urna, at venenatis purus. In vitae pellentesque arcu. Maecenas fringilla arcu sed dolor sollicitudin, ut aliquet nisi auctor.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam dictum lacus et ornare mollis. Suspendisse potenti. Donec eu leo porttitor, ullamcorper arcu at, sagittis augue. Praesent ante urna, pellentesque
        sed interdum in, malesuada sit amet turpis. Mauris imperdiet et ipsum at hendrerit. Nunc facilisis quam eu rutrum cursus. Quisque convallis ante eu ultrices varius. Cras et sapien odio. Morbi quis dui vitae tellus mattis eleifend. Vestibulum posuere
        sapien elit, nec pretium metus pulvinar nec. Aliquam bibendum magna sit amet urna blandit lobortis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</div>
```

I have also created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXqZwr) example. Here's a image of how it looks and how I'd like it to look:

[image: example image of current scroller with the desired effect below it]

Update:
Out of the answers below, I was able to create the exact solution I needed:  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewePmL?editors=1100) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want two independent rows on mobile screens, and the cards to merge together (as in one container) on larger screens, flexbox may not be the best solution.

CSS Grid may not be the best solution either – you may need JavaScript – but here's a grid concept that you may find useful:

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/orowNW?editors=1100)

```css
.box-flex-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 45%));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

@media (max-width: 601px) {
  .m4:nth-child(-n + 6) {
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .m4:nth-child(n + 6) {
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .box-flex-row {
    grid-template-columns: none;
    grid-auto-columns: 45%;
  }
}

.m4 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.m4:nth-child(-n + 6) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.m4:nth-child(n + 6) {
  background-color: orange;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row box-flex-row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 1 upper</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 2 upper</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 3 upper</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 4 upper</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 5 upper</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 1 lower</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 2 lower</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 3 lower</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 4 lower</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 5 lower</div>
      <div class="col s12 m4">test 6 lower</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one flex container with a row of items and horizontal scroll.

You want two rows and horizontal scroll.

So put the two rows in a larger flex container with `flex-direction: column`.

Give the nested row containers full width.

Add the scroll function to the larger container.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEGQMM)

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box-flex-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.box-flex-row > .m4 {
  min-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="section">

    <div class="row box-flex-row">

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row box-flex-row">

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <a href="#" style="display: block;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3 class="black-text">Test</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1e39ef">
              <p class="blue-grey-text">Lower test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B One thing I forgot to mention, is that I wanted this to happen only when the user in on a mobile device. Here is my edited version that kind of does that: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVEQrQ?editors=1100
The issue is that when it grows, there are 2 missing places due to the HTML structure. Would you have a way around this?

Comment: You mean that the second line of items needs to merge with the first line on larger screens? In that case, you would need to put all items in the same container, and work from there.

Comment: I've created another answer that uses CSS Grid.

Comment: @jLynx "I want this to happen only on a mobile device" is really a different concern (e.g. the search phrase to find how to do that is "how to use media queries"). Questions on SO should ideally focus on one thing.

Answer (score 1):

I messed around with it and I think I found a solution.
By setting `flex: column` and height of content to 50%, it'll create two infinite rows.
When you want it to display regularly for desktop, set `flex: row` and set the width of content to 30% with `flex: 0 0 30%`. Not sure if it's the best way to do it but it's the only way I found that worked.

```css
.scroll-container{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    overflow-x: scroll;

}
.scroll-content{
    height: 125px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:rgb(77, 162, 241);
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.scroll-content:nth-child(2n+1){
    background-color: rgb(43, 156, 43); 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px){
    .scroll-container{
        overflow-x: unset;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 700px;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .scroll-content{
        width: 10px;
        flex: 0 0 30%; 
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll-container'>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 1</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 2</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 3</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 4</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 5</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 6</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 7</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 8</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 9</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 10</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 11</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 12</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 13</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 14</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 15</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 16</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 17</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 18</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 19</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 20</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 21</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 22</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 23</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 24</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 25</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 26</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 27</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 28</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 29</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 30</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 31</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 32</div>
    <div class='scroll-content'>Content 33</div>
</div>
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLzrNw)

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that once you have a viewport larger than the height of two rows, the side scroller doesn't stay a side scroller of two rows; it just keeps creating new rows as height becomes available.